# Error: "Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined."

Tags: sitecore-api

After Installing Sitecore 9 XP1 I am getting this error while "**Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined**".
The XP1 installation was properly done without any error and I am able to login into the CMS.
The error occurs when I select Desktop, content Editor or anything on the Experience Platform other than "Marketing Applications".
Any clue how to fix this.

Comment: Can you see more info in xConnect's log file?

Comment: There are no xConnect logs created which I can refer.

Comment: Check your connectionstrings.config files and make sure you have https:// prefixed in all endpoints.

Comment: Can you can check IIS logs for xConnect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error was mainly due to the **"https://"** missing in the url of xConnect,Referencedata and marketingautomation in my ConnectionStrings.config file.

[image]